GCP Service on IAM page
I received old projects on GCP Google Cloud Providers..
I show the multiple accounts on IAM page and when go inside the each external and internal IP (servers) ,
I show multiple users have access to internal server and external server.
The question , I want to know which users has access to internal server belonging to which Email account on IAM page that created each users.
We reviewed the all logs on explorer log page and Metadata but not founded , we found some of users and most of users not founded, may retention deleted.. we know the difficulties on this part, but need directly solutions..
Example to more understanding:
I show on the internal server exists multiple users such as ali100 , ali200 , jon100 , jon200 .
On IAM page showed multiple emails with different roles :
Alisaeed gmail com
Jonali gmail com
Jonsaee gmail com
Aliasa gmail com
Joneem gmail com

The question which emails accounts above created the users
ali100  ali200  jon100  jon200

I'm voting to close this question as it has nothing to do with programming. Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?

Changes to IAM would be captured in Audit Logs which have 400 day retention.
You can check for these events in Logs Explorer:
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query
and filter for resource.type="audited_resource" you should see some events for calls to google.cloud.resourcemanager.v3.Projects.SetIamPolic

Thanks for reply our issues....I checked but the some users may created before couple of years , I want directly ways on GCP console to know each email account which users created.. I have owner and super admin access on GCP project.
